# Debezium reads binlog newest if offset storage is empty or just created&

Tags: mysql, debezium, mysqlbinlog, binlog

I am running reading binlogs with Debezium, but when I start new reading thread it reads all create statements for table from the beginning, but I dont need them(`op=c`). I need to handle create/update/delete events that happens after I run code first time. And than work with correct offset (that stored in file "tmp/offsets.dat"), so how I can set initial configuration in this way? So the flow need to be the next one:

- start reading(first time) -> take current(latest position from binlog and save it, work from here) and handle newest events
- start reading(not the first run) -> take latest position from file and read data as usual

Here is my current configurations

```
  config = Configuration.empty().withSystemProperties(Function.identity()).edit()
            .with(MySqlConnectorConfig.SERVER_NAME, SERVER_NAME)
            .with(MySqlConnectorConfig.SKIPPED_OPERATIONS, "r")
            .with(MySqlConnectorConfig.HOSTNAME, HOSTNAME)
            .with(MySqlConnectorConfig.PORT, PORT)
            .with(MySqlConnectorConfig.USER, USER)
            .with(MySqlConnectorConfig.PASSWORD, PASSWORD)
            .with(MySqlConnectorConfig.TABLE_WHITELIST, TABLE_WHITELIST)
            .with(MySqlConnectorConfig.SERVER_ID, 100)
            // 
            .with(EmbeddedEngine.OFFSET_STORAGE, "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore")
            .with(EmbeddedEngine.OFFSET_STORAGE_FILE_FILENAME, "tmp/offsets.dat")
            .with(EmbeddedEngine.CONNECTOR_CLASS, "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector")
            .with(EmbeddedEngine.ENGINE_NAME, SERVER_NAME)
            //
            .with(MySqlConnectorConfig.DATABASE_HISTORY, "io.debezium.relational.history.FileDatabaseHistory")
            .with("database.history.file.filename", "tmp/dbhistory.dat")
            // Send JSON without schema
            .with("schemas.enable", false)
            .build();
```

and `my.cnf` values for binlogs

```
[mysqld]
log-bin=mysql-bin.log
server_id=100
binlog_row_image=full
binlog-format=row
expire_logs_days =10
```

Comment: One way to solve the issue
this would require `schema_only` snaphsot mode that is not yet supported by MySQL connector(but works for me). I think `schema_only_recovery` mode could be tricked into doing what was described here. After first record was handled you can switch to any type of snapshot mode.

Comment: so the flow is next `File tempFile = new File("tmp/offsets.dat");           MySqlConnectorConfig.SnapshotMode snapshotMod =    MySqlConnectorConfig.SnapshotMode.SCHEMA_ONLY;                                 if (tempFile.exists()) {                                                      snapshotMod = MySqlConnectorConfig.SnapshotMode.INITIAL; }`